# How can I remove this vertical separator line from the last row?

Tags: tables, longtable

I was trying to make a table for school and it has to be done according to the OCTAVE allegro method. On the last row of the table, I have a nested table but the separator from my `longtable` is affecting the nested `tabular` and the vertical line is intersecting my text.

```
     \begin{longtable}{|p{10em}|p{14em}|p{14em}|}
         \hline
         Allegro Worksheet 8 &\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Critical Information Asset Profile} \\
         \hline
        \makecell*[{{p{11em}}}]{\textbf{(1) Critical Asset} \\ \\
        \textit{What is the critical information asset?}} &
        \makecell*[{{p{14em}}}]{\textbf{(2) Rationale for Selection}  \\ \\
        \textit{Why is this information asset important to
        the organization?}} & 
        \makecell*[{{p{11em}}}]{\textbf{(3) Description}\\ \\
        \textit{What is the agreed-upon description of
        this information asset?}} \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{5cm}|}{\textbf{ text goes here}} 
        &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{4cm}|}{\textbf{Text goes here}}
        &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{5cm}|}{\textbf{text goes here}} \\ 
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}|{l|}{\makecell*[{{p{16em}}}]{\textbf{(4) Owner(s)}\\ \\
        \textit{Who owns this information asset?}}} &\\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}|{l|}{\makecell*[{{p{16em}}}]{\textbf{ Answer goes here.................}}} &\\
        \hline
        \renewcommand\labelitemi{$\square$}
        \begin{itemize}
         \item \textbf{Confidentiality}
        \end{itemize}
        &
        Only authorized personnel can view this information asset, as follows:
        & 
        \\
        \hline
         \renewcommand\labelitemi{$\square$}
        \begin{itemize}
         \item \textbf{Integrity}
        \end{itemize}
        &
        Only authorized personnel can view this information asset, as follows:
        & 
        \\
        \hline
      \makecell*[{{p{14em}}}]{\renewcommand\labelitemi{$\square$}
        \begin{itemize}
         \item \textbf{Availability}
        \end{itemize}} 
        &
        \makecell*[{{p{14em}}}]{This asset must be available for these personnel to do their jobs, as follows:
        \\ \\
        This asset must be available for ... hours, ... days/week, ... weeks/year. } 
        & 
        \makecell*[{{p{14em}}}]{ 
        \\ \\ } 
        \\ \hline
        \renewcommand\labelitemi{$\square$}
        \begin{itemize}
         \item \textbf{Other}
        \end{itemize}
        &
        Only authorized personnel can view this information asset, as follows:
        & 
        \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}|{l}{\makecell*[{{p{30em}}}]{\textbf{(6) Most important Security Requirement}\\ \\
        \textit{What is the most important security requirement for this information asset.?}}} &\\
        \hline
        \begin{tabular}{p{10em}|p{10.65em}|p{10em}|p{10em}|}
        \renewcommand\labelitemi{$\square$}
        \begin{itemize}
         \item \textbf{Confidentiality}
        \end{itemize} 
        & 
        \renewcommand\labelitemi{$\square$}
        \begin{itemize}
         \item \textbf{Integrity}
        \end{itemize}
        &
        \renewcommand\labelitemi{$\square$}
        \begin{itemize}
         \item \textbf{Availability}
        \end{itemize}
        & 
        \renewcommand\labelitemi{$\square$}
        \begin{itemize}
         \item \textbf{Other}
        \end{itemize}
         \end{tabular} \\
         \hline
         \end{longtable}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your code currently doesn't compile due to various missing opening and closing curly braces. Please fix.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an improved version of your table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{checkbox}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[checkbox]{label=$\square$,
                   topsep = 0pt,
                   partopsep = 0pt,
                   before = \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
                   leftmargin=*}
\newenvironment{enumsquare}[1][]
 {\begin{checkbox}[before=\bfseries,#1]}
 {\end{checkbox}}
\begin{document}

 \begin{longtable}{|m{4.7cm}|m{4.6cm}|m{4.7cm}|}
    \hline
    Allegro Worksheet 8 &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Critical Information Asset Profile} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{(1) Critical Asset} & \textbf{(2) Rationale for Selection} & \textbf{(3) Description} \\[1ex]
    \textit{What is the critical information asset?} &
    \textit{Why is this information asset important to the organization?} & 
    \textit{What is the agreed-upon description of  this information asset?} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{ text goes here} 
    &
    \textbf{Text goes here}
    &
    \textbf{text goes here} \\ 
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{(4) Owner(s)}}\\[1ex]
    \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textit{Who owns this information asset?}}\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{ Answer goes here.................}}\\
    \hline
    \begin{enumsquare}
     \item Confidentiality
    \end{enumsquare}
    &
    Only authorized personnel can view this information asset, as follows:
    & 
    \\
    \hline
    \begin{enumsquare}
     \item Integrity
    \end{enumsquare}
    &
    Only authorized personnel can view this information asset, as follows:
   & 
   \\
   \hline
   \begin{enumsquare}
    \item Availability
   \end{enumsquare}
   &
   \makecell[{{m{4.6cm}}}t]{This asset must be available for these personnel to do their jobs, as follows:
   \\This asset must be available for ... hours, ... days/week, ... weeks/year. }
   & 
   \\
   \hline
   \begin{enumsquare}
    \item Other
   \end{enumsquare}
   &
   Only authorized personnel can view this information asset, as follows:
   & 
   \\
   \hline 
   \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{(6) Most important Security Requirement}}\\[1ex]
   \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textit{What is the most important security requirement for this information asset.?}}\\
   \hline
   \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{
   \begin{tabular}{m{10em}|m{10em}|m{10em}|m{10em}}
   \begin{enumsquare}
    \item Confidentiality
   \end{enumsquare} 
   & 
   \begin{enumsquare}
    \item Integrity
   \end{enumsquare}
   &
   \begin{enumsquare}
    \item Availability
   \end{enumsquare}
   & 
   \begin{enumsquare}
    \item Other
   \end{enumsquare}
    \end{tabular} }\\
    \hline
    \end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Changes I made in comparison to the original code:

- Enclosed the nested table into a multicolumn environment to get rid of the vertical line
- Removed unneccessary `\multicolumn`  commands
- Defined new custom list to get rid of the repeated `\renewcommand\labelitemi{$\square$}` and `\textbf` commands
- Removed some of the `|` that caused inconsistent line thicknesses
- Removed most of the `makecell` commands.
- ...

General remark: Due to all the vertical and horizontal lines, your table looks very cramped. In the follwing MWE, I have therefor removed all lines and instead inserted some horizontal rules from the `booktabs` package as well as some white spaces as a guide to the eye:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{fullpage}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \newlist{checkbox}{itemize}{2}
    \setlist[checkbox]{label=$\square$,
                       topsep = 0pt,
                       partopsep = 0pt,
                       before = \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
                       leftmargin=*}
    \newenvironment{enumsquare}[1][]
     {\begin{checkbox}[before=\bfseries,#1]}
     {\end{checkbox}}
     \usepackage{booktabs}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{m{4.7cm}m{4.6cm}m{4.7cm}}

    Allegro Worksheet 8 &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Critical Information Asset Profile} \\
    \toprule
    \textbf{(1) Critical Asset} & \textbf{(2) Rationale for Selection} & \textbf{(3) Description} \\[1ex]
    \textit{What is the critical information asset?} &
    \textit{Why is this information asset important to the organization?} & 
    \textit{What is the agreed-upon description of  this information asset?} \\
    \textbf{ text goes here} 
    &
    \textbf{Text goes here}
    &
    \textbf{text goes here} \\ 
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{(4) Owner(s)}}\\[1ex]
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textit{Who owns this information asset?}}\\
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{ Answer goes here.................}}\\
    \midrule
    \begin{enumsquare}
     \item Confidentiality
    \end{enumsquare}
    &
    Only authorized personnel can view this information asset, as follows:
    & 
    \\ \addlinespace
    \begin{enumsquare}
     \item Integrity
    \end{enumsquare}
    &
    Only authorized personnel can view this information asset, as follows:
   & 
   \\  \addlinespace
   \begin{enumsquare}
    \item Availability
   \end{enumsquare}
   &
   \makecell[{{m{4.6cm}}}t]{This asset must be available for these personnel to do their jobs, as follows:
   \\This asset must be available for ... hours, ... days/week, ... weeks/year. }
   & 
   \\ \addlinespace
   \begin{enumsquare}
    \item Other
   \end{enumsquare}
   &
   Only authorized personnel can view this information asset, as follows:
   & 
   \\
   \midrule 
   \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{(6) Most important Security Requirement}}\\[1ex]
   \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textit{What is the most important security requirement for this information asset.?}}\\
   \multicolumn{3}{l}{
   \begin{tabular}{m{10em}m{10em}m{10em}m{10em}}
   \begin{enumsquare}
    \item Confidentiality
   \end{enumsquare} 
   & 
   \begin{enumsquare}
    \item Integrity
   \end{enumsquare}
   &
   \begin{enumsquare}
    \item Availability
   \end{enumsquare}
   & 
   \begin{enumsquare}
    \item Other
   \end{enumsquare}
    \end{tabular} }\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]